# Difference between listing and iterating over an iterator in Python 2.7.6

Tags: python, python-2.7

I have recently been playing around with some code recently which involved an iterator:

```
"""IntegerPartitions.py

Generate and manipulate partitions of integers into sums of integers.

D. Eppstein, August 2005.

https://www.ics.uci.edu/~eppstein/PADS/IntegerPartitions.py
"""

def mckay(n):
    """
    Integer partitions of n, in reverse lexicographic order.
    The output and asymptotic runtime are the same as mckay(n),
    but the algorithm is different: it involves no division,
    and is simpler than mckay, but uses O(n) extra space for
    a recursive call stack.
    """
    if n == 0:
        yield []
    if n <= 0:
        return
    for p in mckay(n-1):
        if len(p) == 1 or (len(p) > 1 and p[-1] < p[-2]):
            p[-1] += 1
            yield p
            p[-1] -= 1
        p.append(1)
        yield p
        p.pop()
```

The program takes in an integer, and returns a generator which outputs the partitions of that integer.

I have noticed something weird, however, when I try to use it in code.

```
>>> p = mckay(4)
>>> print list(p)
[[], [], [], [], []]
>>> q = mckay(4)
>>> cumulator = []
>>> for x in q :
...     cumulator.append(x)
>>> print cumulator
[[], [], [], [], []]
>>> print list(mckay(4))
[[], [], [], [], []]
>>> r = mckay(4)
>>> for x in r :
...     print x
[4]
[3, 1]
[2, 2]
[2, 1, 1]
[1, 1, 1, 1]
>>> for x in mckay(4) :
...     print x
[4]
[3, 1]
[2, 2]
[2, 1, 1]
[1, 1, 1, 1]
```

The partitions don't seem to show up unless I print them one by one.  Is this a bug in the language (my version is Python 2.7.6 on Ubuntu Trusty), or is there something I am missing?  I have looked around on Google, and cannot seem to find anything pertaining to this.

I thought it may have something to do with the recursive call, but I tried it with the following code, and found similar results

```
def mckay(n):
    """
    Integer partitions of n, in reverse lexicographic order.
    Note that the generated output consists of the same list object,
    repeated the correct number of times; the caller must leave this
    list unchanged, and must make a copy of any partition that is
    intended to last longer than the next call into the generator.
    The algorithm follows Knuth v4 fasc3 p38 in rough outline.
    """
    if n == 0:
        yield []
    if n <= 0:
        return
    partition = [n]
    last_nonunit = (n > 1) - 1
    while True:
        yield partition
        if last_nonunit < 0:
            return
        if partition[last_nonunit] == 2:
            partition[last_nonunit] = 1
            partition.append(1)
            last_nonunit -= 1
            continue
        replacement = partition[last_nonunit] - 1
        total_replaced = replacement + len(partition) - last_nonunit
        reps,rest = divmod(total_replaced,replacement)
        partition[last_nonunit:] = reps*[replacement]
        if rest:
            partition.append(rest)
        last_nonunit = len(partition) - (partition[-1]==1) - 1
```

The results are almost identical:

```
>>> p = mckay(4)
>>> print list(p)
[[1, 1, 1, 1], [1, 1, 1, 1], [1, 1, 1, 1], [1, 1, 1, 1], [1, 1, 1, 1]]
>>> q = mckay(4)
>>> cumulator = []
>>> for x in q :
...     cumulator.append(x)
>>> print cumulator
[[1, 1, 1, 1], [1, 1, 1, 1], [1, 1, 1, 1], [1, 1, 1, 1], [1, 1, 1, 1]]
>>> print list(mckay(4))
[[1, 1, 1, 1], [1, 1, 1, 1], [1, 1, 1, 1], [1, 1, 1, 1], [1, 1, 1, 1]]
>>> r = mckay(4)
>>> for x in r :
...     print x
[4]
[3, 1]
[2, 2]
[2, 1, 1]
[1, 1, 1, 1]
>>> for x in mckay(4) :
...     print x
[4]
[3, 1]
[2, 2]
[2, 1, 1]
[1, 1, 1, 1]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that the function `mckay` is modifying the same list object, so when you call `list()` on it you actually get a list containing 4 items that actually point to the same object. So, as in the end the list object is empty all you get is list with empty lists.

```
>>> p = mckay(4)
>>> [id(x) for x in p]
[139854369904832, 139854369904832, 139854369904832, 139854369904832, 139854369904832]

>>> for x in mckay(4):
    print x, '-->', id(x)

[4] --> 140446845125552
[3, 1] --> 140446845125552
[2, 2] --> 140446845125552
[2, 1, 1] --> 140446845125552
[1, 1, 1, 1] --> 140446845125552
>>> x # The actual list object is empty at the end of the iteration
[]
>>> id(x)
140446845125552
```

But when you loop over it you're simply printing the returned object immediately hence the different output, a fix here is to yield a shallow copy:

```
yield p[:]
```